# Doggy door: Dog will go outside but not inside

Tags: dogs, training

My dog knows how to use the doggy door. She would go in and out. I’ve only had it for a week however. Now she just goes outside but seems to forget how to come back inside. She will just stand at the doggy door even when she sees my other dog come back inside she still stands outside like if the doggy door is closed.

Comment: Welcome! The users of this Q&A site will help you best, if you add a question (question mark) or an aim you want to reach. Use the "edit" button to add this into your post